# Can I turn a string which looks like the contents of an array into an array?

Tags: arrays, string, perl, split

I have a string read in from a text file which would be the equivalent of me declaring it in the following format:

```
$string = '["Item1_Field1","Item1_Field2","Item1_Field3"],["Item2_Field1","Item2_Field2","Item2_Field3"],["Item3_Field1","Item3_Field2","Item3_Field3"],["Item4_Field1","Item4_Field2","Item4_Field3"]';
```

(The actual string contains about 600 items and about 50 fields)
What I'm trying to do is get is a two dimensional (nested) array of the Items and Fields such that I can refer to them using something like:

```
print $ItemsAndFields[1][2]
```

which would result in (allowing for zero-based arrays):

```
Item2_Field3
```

It occurs to me that the string is in a very similar format to how you'd declare an array in Perl, so I'm hoping there is something similar to the following to allow me to assign the items to an array directly:

```
@ItemsAndFields = magicfunction( $string );
```

but I can't find anything suitable that allows me to use the string in this way.

The only way I can see to do this otherwise is to use split function twice to create this array of an array.  The following is untested, just a work in progress in my head:

```
$string =~ s/\[//g;
my @items = split(/\],*/, $string);
my @ItemsAndFields = split(/\,/, $string);
```

I tried looking at the eval() function, the use of {} references as well as searching this site, but it's difficult to know what I need to search for.

Any help appreciated, I'm new to Perl.

Answer (score 5):

```
my $arrayRef = eval "[$string]";
```

will give you:

```
$arrayRef = [
      [
        'Item1_Field1',
        'Item1_Field2',
        'Item1_Field3'
      ],
      [
        'Item2_Field1',
        'Item2_Field2',
        'Item2_Field3'
      ],
      [
        'Item3_Field1',
        'Item3_Field2',
        'Item3_Field3'
      ],
      [
        'Item4_Field1',
        'Item4_Field2',
        'Item4_Field3'
      ]
    ];
```

which you can then access like this:

```
my $item2Field3 = $arrayRef->[1]->[2];
```

Comment: why not `my @ItemsAndFields = eval "($string)";` then its exactly what the OP asked for?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `eval` for this, but since your data does not require evaluation, just parsing, it is better to parse it with something like the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) module.

```
use JSON 'decode_json';

my $data = decode_json "[$string]";

say $$_[0] for @$data;
```

which prints:

```
Item1_Field1
Item2_Field1
Item3_Field1
Item4_Field1
```

This avoids any issues with evaluating code in the data structure.  It should also be faster than `eval`.

Comment: Do note that `eval` really is the answer here. Using JSON here works for nested arrays because Perl and JSON have the same structure for arrays. You will need `eval` in general, because of hashes; Perl and JSON differ on hash notation.

Comment: @JoelBerger => Sorry, but you are wrong.  `eval` should NEVER be used to parse input data if there is another way.  If absolutely necessary, then `Safe` should be used to restrict the `eval` as much as possible.  But it is probably better to either deal with the differences between Perl's notation and JSON (either by transforming `:` to `=>` between quotes, or by finding a way to make JSON use `=>` as the record separator while parsing).  But since we have no idea where the OP's data is coming from, suggesting `eval` is both foolish and dangerous.

Comment: If the data is coming from an unsafe source then you are absolutely correct Eric. But the OP has data that he can see. Anyway I read the question as, is there a way to turn a Perl-ish string into Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

You really are looking for the `eval` function. Part of the reason that `eval` is hard to understand at first is that there are two different forms of `eval` which are very different.

- `eval {block}`
- `eval "string"`

The block form is for trapping exceptions and isn't important here. The string form is the real magical form. Basically it takes your string and runs is as a mini Perl program, returning the last evaluated statement.

Your answer is therefore:

```
my @ItemsAndFields = eval "($string)";
```

other uses of `eval` might be

```
my $name = "Joel";
my $sub = eval 'sub { print "Hello ' . $name . '"}';
$sub->();
```

In which you dynamically create a string which would be a subroutine reference, and then you spring it to life with `eval`. (Of course you probably don't need to do dynamic code generation that way, its just an example.)